# EXCEL FORMULA IN PIVOT TABLE

Tags: excel, pivot, formula

How to apply the following excel formula in pivot calculated field.

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY())>10,IF(SUM(K2:N2)>499,"Locked",""),IF(SUM(L2:N2)>499,"Locked",""))
```

Please help and advise
Thanks
CSGanesh

Comment: Use the Power Pivot tool

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. We have no idea what those cell references point at.  Please clarify what you want the formula to do. Consider posting a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated Fields can't reference cell references...they can only reference other PivotTable fields.